# Can't see class from within a package

Tags: java, package

I have a Java project built using IDEA and Maven. To make this question simple:
suppose part of the structure of the project is 
src -> main -> java
In java folder there is a package called PAK, for example, which contains class A. Also there is  class B in java folder without package.
The problem is when I'm trying next code

```
package PAK;

public class A {

       private B variable;
}
```

compiler can't see class B but class B is public.

Comment: we need more input. are there any errors when you try to compile your code?

Comment: Errors are simple: Cannot resolve symbol B

Comment: please show us the declaration of class B

Comment: try to compile both classes using commandline

Comment: Suppose class B is as simple as it possible public class B {
}

Comment: then use the commandline to compile both classes

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the class B, because it's not in the same package with A

```
package PAK;

import B;

public class A {

    private B variable;

}
```

If classes are in the same package, you don't need to import them.

Comment: it doesnt help. When Im trying to write import B i see again line Cannot resolve symbol B